# Azure app insights viewer

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I recently setup two of our apps to use app insights (coming from Elmah). But now I need to give the QA and BA teams access to view the error logs. What's the best way to do this? Do they need an azure account as well? Is there a windows app viewer, etc? I fear navigating the azure portal might be a little too complicated for them.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They don't need to have Azure account to view AI resource in Azure, as they need is live ID. You can add them clicking on Users icon-> Users blade -> [Add access](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/role-based-access-control-configure/).
[image]

I would say this is the easiest way, another approach would be to [set up Continuous export and export data to something like PowerBI](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-export-power-bi/), but this is much more involved.